# Convert split data into dataframe in r

Tags: r

Please, can anyone explain to me how to put this split data (Fibre) into a dataframe in r. So that I can have two columns: Group and Observation.

```
Fibre

[[1]]
12.5, 5, 4.5, 6, 10.2, 9.6, 15.5, 12.2, 13, 17.5, 13, 14

[[2]]
11.5, 7, 4.5, 8, 13.2, 19.6, 13.5, 15.2, 13.5, 20,17

[[3]]
10.5, 6, 8.5, 8, 11.2, 14.6, 19.5, 15.9, 14.5, 21,12,15,17,18

[[4]]
9.5, 16, 9.5, 8.5, 13.5, 12.6, 11.5, 16.7, 14, 19.5
```

I used:

```
NewData <- as.data.frame(Fibre)
```

Comment: You have 4 vectors in a list. You say you want to convert them into 2 columns `Group` and `Observation`. Which values go with which? Or is each vector a group?

Comment: My best guess is `data.frame(Group = rep(1:length(Fibre), times = lengths(Fibre)), Observation = unlist(Fibre))`, but it would be nice to see the output you're hoping for so I can know if my guess is right.